# Defining the predicates using choosen symbols.

Tags: logic

Let the range of variatons of variables be the set of natural numbers. Show that using the symbols 0, 1, + and | we can define the predicate "x * y = z" (the symbol | means divisibility without remainder).

I have also a hint:
Define the predicate (∃y) (x = y^2) first.
You may need the following identities
(x + y)^2 = x^2 + xy + xy + y^2 , GCD(x, x + 1) = 1 and x^2 + x = LCM(x, x + 1),
where GCD is greatest common divisor, LCM is least common multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE!

Your hint is a good one. I'll try to explain it in slightly more depth since this is a kind of tricky problem.

---

We want to express $xy = z$. But we only have access to the symbols $0,1,+,\mid,=$.

The trick is to leverage the identity $(x+y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2$. From this, we know that

$$z=xy \iff (x+y)^2 = x^2 + z + z + y^2.$$

So we've reduced our problem (defining *all* multiplication) to a special case (defining *perfect squares*).

---

OK, can we find a way to write $k = x^2$? Here is where the hint regarding gcd and lcm comes into play. Since $\text{lcm}(x,x+1) = x^2 + x$, we see

$$ k = x^2 \iff \text{lcm}(x,x+1) = k+x $$

---

So now we're almost done. Here is a step-by-step guide you might use to finish the problem:

1. Can you write $\mathtt{LCM}(x,y,z)$, an expression which is true if and only if $z = \text{lcm}(x,y)$?
   You should be able to do this using the divisibility relation $\mid$.
2. Then define $\mathtt{Square}(x,y) = \exists l . \text{isLCM}(x,x+1,l) \land l = y+x$.
   Do you see why $\mathtt{Square}(x,y)$ is true if and only if $y=x^2$?
3. Finally, define $\mathtt{Prod}(x,y,z) = \exists X . \exists Y . \exists S . \mathtt{Square}(x,X) \land \mathtt{Square}(y,Y) \land \mathtt{Square}(x+y,S) \land S = X + z + z + Y$
   Do you see why this correctly defines $\mathtt{Prod}(x,y,z) \iff xy = z$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you for really extensive answer. Everything is clear to me to the point, when I have to define the LCM of three numbers. I don't understand how is it related to the final answer. I am not sure how to write LCM(x,y,z) in such a way that you explained me in the answer. I figured out, that if z = LCM(x,y), then LCM(x,y,z) = LCM(x,y, LCM(x,y)) = LCM(x,y) . I don't know how to achive that using the divisibility relation. Could you help me one more time? I would really appreciate it. Have a good day!

Comment: And also I am not sure, why the Square(x,y) is true <==> y = x^2 . I see this, when for example, x = 9, then y = 3, then LCM(3,4,l ) and l = 12, so the l is just 3*4, this means that l = 3*4, right? But why is it true only if y = x^2? Sorry for asking maybe so easy questions, but I had just started this subject at university, and I haven't completed many exercises yet.

Comment: Here's a hint for defining LCM(x,y): you know x and y have to divide LCM(x,y). Moreover, LCM is _least_ with this property. Can you express that in terms of divisibility too?

Comment: And the idea with SQUARE is that $x^2 + x$ is the LCM of $x$ and $x+1$. We bring $l$ into the picture purely because we can't add a function symbol, only relations. Really what I'm saying is $\text{Square}(x,y) \iff y \text{lcm}(x,x+1) = x + y$. But we need to add in an existential quantifier since LCM is a relation, not a function.